# Sorting multidimensional array twice

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that need to be sorted. I want this array first sorted based on count from high to low. But when count has the same value, sort by city alphabetically. I don't know how to do this.

The multidimensional array:

```
Array
    (

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [city] => c
            [count] => 5 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [city] => b
            [count] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [city] => a
            [count] => 5
        )
)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

this is the result that i want:

```
Array
    (

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [city] => b
            [count] => 10 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [city] => a
            [count] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [city] => c
            [count] => 5
        )
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i usually do it..

```
$test = array(array('id'=> '2', 'city'=> 'c', 'count' => '5'),array('id'=> '3', 'city'=> 'b', 'count' => '10'),array('id'=> '4', 'city'=> 'a', 'count' => '5'));

function cmp($a, $b){
    if($a['count'] == $b['count']){
        if($a['city'] == $b['city']){
            return 0;
        }return $a['city'] < $b['city'] ? -1 : 1;
    }else{
         return $a['count'] > $b['count'] ? -1 : 1;
    }
 }

uasort($test , 'cmp');
```

result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [city] => b
            [count] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [city] => a
            [count] => 5
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [city] => c
            [count] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: works fine. But i want the highest count first. how to do that?

Comment: change `ksort($newArr);` to `krsort($newArr);` please select as answer if it helps you thanks ^_^

Comment: it doenst work. The array with the most counts is first now, but the second array is the array where city is c and that is wrong.

Comment: soo the city should still be sort a to z?

Comment: yes, i want to sort the count from high to low. if count is the same, then sort those a to z. the result should be: array[2],array[0],array[1]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a user defined function like:

```
function($a, $b) {
  if($a['count'] === $b['count']) {
    if($a['city'] === $b['city']) {
      return 0;
    }
    return $a['city'] < $b['city'] ? -1 : 1;
  } else {
    return $a['count'] < $b['count'] ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has many different methods and even a good overview page for exactly this kind of question: http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Once you figure out a method and have trouble executing it then you can ask a more specific question.